# The right way to get the selector of a jQuery plugin call now that the .selector property was deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I know that the selector of a jQuery plugin call can be get using the `.selector` property but it is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and may be removed without notice in a future version.

```
$.fn.myplugin = function() {
    console.log( this.selector );
};
// ...
$( '#selector' ).myplugin(); // #selector
```

What's the right way to get the selector of a plugin call now that the `.selector` property was deprecated?

I need to get the plugin call's selector because my plugin's option need to have a selector which sometimes the same as the plugin call's selector, so I can check if they're the same:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function( options ) {
    var opts = $.extend( { }, $.fn.myplugin.defaults, options );
    if ( opts.selector === this.selector ) {
        // if arg selector is the same as plugin call's selector
    } else {
        // if they're not the same
    }
};
$.fn.myplugin.defaults = {
    selector: '#default'
};
// ...
$( '#same' ).myplugin( {
    selector: '#same'
} );
```

Comment: What if the object calling the plugin was not obtained through a selector?

Comment: @BoltClock Currently, my plugin needs to be called by the object that's obtained through a selector.